# Arithmetic operators against varchar data in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

Could someone please explain to me how arithmetic operators such as > or < compare strings in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 1):

If they are against a numeric field, they work about as you would expect. If it's against a character type of data field, they would work alphabetically. So if you wanted greater than (>)10 and less than (<)20 you might get 11, 110, 123456 in response.

This is one reson why it is always a bad idea to store numbers you want to be able to do math calculations or comparisons with as varchar (or any other type of char data). Only numbers that do not need math calculations (phone, zip, ssn, etc.) should be stored that way and those should always be stored in a character type field to account for leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting (and thus the < > operators) depends on your SQL Server collation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250(SQL.90).aspx

And the rules for that collation you'd have to find on the web. Note that they are often very complicated. For your sake, I'd try and avoid < and > comparisons of VARCHAR's unless you really, really need to.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the quick response.

The reason that I'm asking is that I need to query a database table of UK postcodes. The table in question has two postcode columns, "from_postcode" and "to_postcode" and I need to determine whether a given postcode lies between these values.

Fortunately the data has been laid out in such a way that I think I should be able to use the arithmetic operators to at least get a subset of rows of potential matches.

Time for me to write a few (or perhaps a fair few) uni tests!